# Combining multiple forms to submit

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a survey and have users input text, answer some questions, etc. but I don't know how to combine them to recieve the info back.

So basically what I'm trying to do is combine multiple ["jQuery Mobile Forms"](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_examples.asp) (scroll down) and have them return the values. As you can see in this [single one](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_radio), it does it perfectly, but when I try to add another form and submit, I will only get 1 form submitted.

Comment: You can put as many `input` as you want in a `form`. You don't have to make multiple `form`s.

Comment: Why do use multiple forms? Just us a single one

Comment: I see. Also, how would you go about making a form that is self submitting, so I can send the form and receive it offline, [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_legend) but not server-sided.

Comment: @ryubro not entirely true ... some servers have post field limits as attempt to mitigate attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to achieve what you want -

1. Use one form element and place multiple controls in it.
2. Use jQuery to get all the values of controls and make a POST/GET request to the server via ajax.